# run task on specific time in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can we run some task on specific time in background if my application is running or on dormant state. Is this possible in windows phone 7.5 Mango. If Its not possible then any work around with the help of push notifications.

Comment: but in case my app is not in running state then.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not the currently active application in Windows Phone your application is being tombstoned, which means that some of your state is saved and your application is halted (e.g. there is no code running for your application anymore).
Therefor you can not create code that allows your application to do anything at a specific time, without using push notification.
Even with push notification your options are very limited. It realy depends on what you want to happen when a notification arives.